# angular spa app not refreshing when running through visual studio 2017 community

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am having issues where my angular 6 app will not refresh when running through visual studio 2017. The solution has multiple projects in it and has multiple startup projects. One is a .net core 2 webapi and the other the angular app in question.

I have tried setting the startup to only be on the angular app but this doesn't make a difference?

If I run the project the page renders fine, however, if I then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> or <kbd>f5</kbd>, I get stuck with the standard angular 'loading...' text and it fails to load the following files;

vendor.css, vendor.js, main-client.js

However if it then stop running the project and rebuild and run the changes are reflected when ti first runs. but again I cant make refresh the page.

Please see the screenshot below.

[image: browser screenshot]

This is project specific, as I have tried opening up another solution, running it, then editing a .html file and refreshing and the changes are reflected straight away.

Answer (score 1):

Issue: Well above error occur because website is not able find css, js files.

Root cause: folder structure.

e.g.
     root folder
           - api
           - webpanel

Solution: at the time of build cmd use

ng build --base="/webpanel/"

Let me know, if anything I missed out

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? I think it’s something to do with the jit recompiling the js and css. As it’s only when I make changes does the reload fail? It’s seems odd that f5 works when no changes are made. I.e. it can resolve the files.